# What happens if I pass a variable value instead of a variable reference in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have this code:

```
int a;

scanf("%d", &a);

printf("You entered: %d", a);
```

which works perfectly fine, but I wondered what would happen if I pass the variable value instead of the variable reference in `scanf` like `scanf("%d", a)`.

I don't get an error from the compiler but there is no output either.
What is happening here?

Comment: long story short: UB

Comment: If you do not get an error or warning message from your compiler, your compiler is defective. Ensure warnings are turned on in your compiler.

Comment: You'd hope for a hard crash (segfault).  But since the variable is not initialized, there are decent odds that it happens to contain a pointer value left behind by a previous function call.  Now it won't crash but silently corrupt memory, very hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` expects the argument corresponding to the `%d` conversion specifier to be the *address* of an `int` object (with type `int *`).  Whatever *value* `a` contains will be interpreted as an address<sup>1</sup>.

The behavior on doing this is *undefined* - the compiler isn't required to issue a diagnostic during translation, and the runtime environment isn't required to throw any kind of exception.  Depending on the value contained in `a` you may get a runtime error, or you may clobber another data object, or your code may work without any apparent errors, or something completely different may happen.

---

1. At least on systems where `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int *)` - for a system like x86_64, that's not the case, so `scanf` will treat bytes *outside* of `a` as part of an address.

Answer (score 0):

In scanf `"%d"` is expecting a pointer to `int` meaning a pointer to the address of the variable where the value will be stored, if you pass `a` you will just be passing `int` there is no way the value can be stored because `scanf` won't know where.

Doing this will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the & is an operator that returns the address of the operand. If you give in scanf the variable a without the &, it will be passed to it by-value, which means scanf will not be able to set its value for you to see. Passing it by-reference - using & actually passes a pointer to a - allows scanf to set it.

Comment: The term _by-reference_ does not exist within the C language. References are a C++ thing. In C there are only pointers.